# When I click the QpushButton, No change?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7

I use QT designer to design a page that contains two buttons, a start and an end, but when I click them, there is no response. I put them all in widgets, is that why?

**I'm confused. When I click the start or end button，no Change!**

PyQt5 When I click the QpushButton ，No change?

Is it because it's inside the widget?

My code is like this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(640, 480)
        self.widget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget_6.setEnabled(True)
        self.widget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 250, 151, 68))
        self.widget_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.widget_6.setObjectName("widget_6")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_6)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_6)
        self.start_btn.setStyleSheet("")
        self.start_btn.setObjectName("start_btn")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.start_btn)
        self.end_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_6)
        self.end_btn.setStyleSheet("")
        self.end_btn.setObjectName("end_btn")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.end_btn)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.start_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "start"))
        self.end_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "end"))



import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QWidget


class Sorter(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    """
    demo
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        init
        """
        super(Sorter, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = Sorter()
    myWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't understand you, what changes do you expect and why do you expect changes?

Comment: When the button is clicked, the status when the button is pressed is not displayed.

Comment: Do you mean that you expect the appearance of the button to change when you hold down the button compared to the appearance of the button without pressing?

Comment: Normal button when I click the button, its appearance should change, which means that the button has been clicked. However, when I click the start or end button, its appearance will not change, as if it does not take effect.

Comment: Remove `self.start_btn.setStyleSheet("")` and `self.end_btn.setStyleSheet("")`